# Minimum pixel size for facebook share images

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-sharer

I am searching a lot but not able to find the minimum heightxwidth required for facebook share link to show thumbnail.

I tried with my website's logo but it didn't work, then I tried with bigger image and it worked but what is the minimum size required?

Answer (score 2):

In the docs about the [feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) you have this information:

> (...)The URL of a picture attached to this post. The picture must be at least 200px by 200px. See our documentation on maximizing distribution for media content for more information on sizes.

Here you have official info about [Sharing Best Practices](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content/#tags), and you can get more info about other facebook sizes [here](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2012/11/12/final-social-media-sizing-cheat-sheet/)

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure why but this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ is not opening

Comment: well that's weird, I can open that link without any problem

Comment: As of today, the minimum size is 200px x 200px, accordingly to the mentioned page:

Picture: The URL of a picture attached to this post. The picture must be at least 200px by 200px (...).

Fabio Antunes, I think it helps if you update your post, so that hurried people don't get I find it helps if you update your post so that people will not be mistaken.